# How to trigger an exe using command prompt with parameters

Tags: .net, command

I need to trigger an executable file(built using .net) using the command prompt.
For example 
c:> myfile.exe

But the executable which I have needs authentication.Is it possible to trigger the exe with username and password as parameters??

Comment: Depends on the executable. Is it configured to be able to accept command line arguments?

Comment: I wish to schedule this on a scheduler so I need to pass the parameters.

Comment: it is built using dot net.. This exe will only work if we run as 'administrator' that is why I am passing the username pass to the exe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scheduled tasks allow you to set a "Run as" property. You can set the windows user account and password there.

If your only concern is running it under a particular account, you can configure this when you create the scheduled task itself.

If your exe itself demands a user name and password, you will need to pass command line parameters.

Comment: Yes, but I am not going to use scheduled task.I should use a scheduler called 'autosys'

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the Shell Command   **runAs**